# how to fix paypal-setting in django

Tags: django, paypal

i'm integrating paypal in my website so i can use WPP there is a setting need to be done in django settings so i did like they said in this tutorial [django-paypal](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal)
i still get a failure for response while testing payment form

```
PayPal Response:
{'ack': 'Failure',
 'build': '5715372',
 'correlationid': '248fc1aeef2d7',
 'l_errorcode0': '10002',
 'l_longmessage0': 'Security header is not valid',
 'l_severitycode0': 'Error',
 'l_shortmessage0': 'Security error',
 'timestamp': '2013-05-07T10:15:10Z',
 'version': '54.0'}
```

i used this code for using WPP in my website

```
from paypal.pro.views import PayPalPro

def buy_it_now(request):
    item = {
            "business": "imoum0007@gmail.com",
          "amt": "10.00",             
          "inv": "inventory",       
          "custom": "tracking",   
           "notify_url": "/some/obscure/name/",
          "cancelurl": "/account/",  
          "returnurl": "/account/"}
    kw = {"item": item,                          
        "payment_template": "payment.html",     
        "confirm_template": "confirmation.html", 
        "success_url": "/success/"}           

    ppp = PayPalPro(**kw)
    return ppp(request)
```